# Why does throat 'burn' when you've got a common cold?

Tags: human-biology

Apart from pain when swallowing, there's also a persistent feeling of throat 'burning' in the same area.

What causes it and why does it feel that way?

Comment: Could you describe the burning sensation some more? Is it located the same spot as the soreness?

Comment: @Brian well yes, pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you've been sneezing or coughing a lot it is probably micro abrasions in the throat. I don't recognize any other burning sensation.

Comment: My common cold started with sore throat, with no running nose or coughing.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it is because the throat is sore, thus probably inflammated. Inflammations are hot. Though, I am not a doctor.